# Ideal gas formula $PV = nRT$ in Celsius scale

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, unit-conversion

I was wondering how to re-write that ideal gas formula $PV = nRT$ applicable to Celsius or Fahrenheit scale. I know $R$ has unit $\frac{\mathrm J}{\mathrm{mol\cdot K}}$ and $T$ has units in K, that means this formula is derived only for absolute temperature $T$, is that true?

I want to re-write it for Celsius scale. If I change $T = C+273$ and apply $C$ to the formula, does that beget me the right conversion? I think there's more than just converting the temperature scale.

Comment: But you can keep in Celsius for temperature differences, relative is OK, absolute is not,  it must be K.

Comment: Note that there are 10-20 different versions of the ideal gas constant, depending on what pressure, volume, and temperature units you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some [simple conversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_units_of_temperature) to change any temperature scale to Kelvin to work in the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law).

$\text{K} = {}^\circ\text{Celsius} + 273.15$

$\text{K} = (^\circ\text{Fahrenheit}-32)\dfrac{5}{9} + 273.15$

$\text{K} = \dfrac{^\circ\text{Rankine}}{1.8}$

When I first learned the equation pressure was in units of mm of Hg, volume was in liters, and temperature was Kelvin.

Note that since Rankine is an absolute temperature scale too you could use a different value for R which is a constant which depends on the units of pressure, volume and temperature. It would be odd to use English units for temperature and metric units for pressure and volume, so you could convert those values into a different value for R too. So with an appropriate value of R you could have pressure in $\mathrm{lbs/inch}^2$, volume in cubic feet, and temperature in Rankine.

Comment: Note that according to the BIPM the modern name for the unit is "kelvin," not "degrees kelvin."

Answer (score 4):

It only works for absolute temperature. You can convert your temperature in Celsius or Fahrenheit to Kelvin first, then plug in the result in the formula, or you can modify the formula to do that for you:
$$PV=nR(T_{°C}+273.15)K$$
Where $T_{°C}$ is the number of the temperature in Celsius and $K$ just stands for Kelvin. Example: if the temperature is $25°C$, then $T_{°C}=25$ and $PV=nR(25+273.15)K=nR(298.15K)$.

Comment: :-( "K" looks like another variable here and superfluous. Just $PV = nR (T_C+273)$ where $T_C$ is the temperature in Celsius.

Comment: @MaxW Agree!   Please edit the formula to remove the $K$.

Comment: It's important to be consistent with the units. If you divide $PV$ by $nR(T_{ºC}+273.15)$, you get $1$ Kelvin.

Comment: The point is that no other variable in the equation has units. It is just weird to add the K. The K looks like a variable not a unit of measure.

Comment: ALL other variables have units. For example, $P=100 Pa$ would be correct, not $P=100$.

Comment: Of course all the variables have units, but the units are not shown in the equation.

Comment: I've converted the abbreviation for "kelvin" to upright type, and attached it to the appropriate numerical value, so that units for all the symbols in this relation are treated the same way.

Comment: So how does $25\text{ }^o\text{C} + 273.15\text{ }^o\text{K}$ get to have units of Kelvin??

Comment: @MaxW rob's edit is wrong. The original formula was correct. The units for the other variables are not shown in the formula because they're included in the variables. The only exception is $T_{ºC}$ because here we want to convert the unit, so we are forced to use the number.

Comment: @rob made an edit to this answer which made the units inconsistent. At the time, I had decided not to engage in an edit war and let it go, but someone has recently upvoted the answer in its wrong version. This bothers me because it spreads misinformation under my username. So I decided to revert the edit.

Comment: @Wood Sorry for introducing confusion. The main purpose of my edit was to convert the abbreviations for the units from $\mathit{slanted}$ to $\mathrm{upright}$ type.  I think of a Celsius temperature as being *defined* as a difference between two Kelvin temperatures ($T_\mathrm C \equiv T_\mathrm K - T_\text{reference}$). From this perspective it makes more sense to attach the kelvin unit to the numerical value of $T_\text{reference} = 273\,\mathrm K$, which you've written out explicitly.  But if it reads more naturally for you to have the $\mathrm K$ outside the parenthesis, go for it.

Comment: I step on this and I have to agree that your 1st writing is misleading. It means either that $K$ is a variable (which it is not) or that the product $PV$ units is kelvin (which it is not, it is en energy). As long as you provide no units for $PV$ it is inconsistent to provide one for the RHS of your equation. You should add clarification below (that's actually the proper way to do, defining your variables outside of the equation) because your style is ambiguous.

Comment: @G.Clavier Obviously $PV$ has units, therefore the RHS has units too. And the unit is not Kelvin, because $nR$ has units. Obviously $K$ is not a variable because I explicitly mentioned that it "just stands for Kelvin". $T_{°C}$ is not the temperature, it's just a number. It's as simple as if $x = 20$, then $x°C$ is a temperature of $20°C$, but $x$ is still just a number. There's absolutely nothing confusing about any of this and therefore this will be my last comment of this sort. If anyone still disagrees, I urge you to read my answer again carefully a few times before commenting.

Comment: You are mismatching units and dimensions. $PV$ has the dimension of an energy but units are context dependent. It makes no sense to add them on one side of the equation and not the other (plus inside or outside parentheses?). When you precise that $T_C$ is the temperature in Celsius degrees and that $R$ is in $J\cdot{}mol^{-1}\cdot{}K^{-1}$ (something you actually never do, you could use other units), then you don't have to precise that the temperature in the expression is in Kelvin.

Your writing is not canonical, ambiguous and this has to be pointed out. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the formula relies on absolute temperature (generally in Kelvins). But by adding 273 to the temperature in degrees Celsius, you are converting to Kelvin, which is the only change you need to make the formula work.

Comment: Note that Celcius and Fahrenheit cannot be used. The temperature must be in Kelvin or Rankin. (Absolute versions of Celsius and Fahrenheit)

Comment: You could use some simple conversions to change any temperature scale to Kelvin. Some conversions are messier than other, but it is possible.